# Junit Test annotation vs test suffix or prefix

Tags: java, junit

I developed a java application and I want to write unit test for it. (I have never written a unit test in java before) I noticed that there are 2 different example by writing Junit test. like E.g. 1

```
public void testExample(){
//do something...
}
```

than E.g. 2

```
@Test
public void Example(){
//do something...
}
```

which one is the more usefull ?

Comment: I use only junit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Test convention](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/are_naming_conventions_for_junit) have changed in JUnit4

There's **no need for test prefix** anymore, just use `@Test` annotation before the method:

> JUnit 3 used naming conventions for the identification of test methods. JUnit 4 uses annotations for that purpose, so that the **prefix "test" is actually superfluous. It is not only superfluous, but also redundant**.
>
> Instead writing something like:
>
> ```
> @Test
>
> public void testAverageTotalStartedThreadCount() {}
> ```
>
> you could just skip the prefix "test" and go with the annotation only:
>
> ```
> @Test
>
> public void averageTotalStartedThreadCount() {}
> ```
>
> The "test" prefixes are still generated by Eclipse and NetBeans, so if you don't like the superfluous naming, you will have to remove it manually. The "test" prefix in the test-class name, however, is still useful. It makes the search for test classes more easy.

Comment: *All* of the text you copy/pasted needs to be properly quoted and attributed. Anything less constitutes plagiarism.

Comment: So that this is the same is it ok ? there are no different. could you give me an example is the best case? thanks :)

Comment: if you are using Junit4 or above no need for test prefix, it's an old convention

Comment: And last question, Sometime  public void testAverageTotalStartedThreadCount() {} example is not working... Why?

Comment: you need to add annotation `@Test` above the method

Comment: the answer is correct, it should be accepted. these is just a code convention in junit or use prefix in prior version of junit4. you also can use prefix `test` in junit4 annotated `@Test`s, just choose one which you like.

Answer (score 1):

For example 1, I assume you are planning to throw exception or log if something goes wrong.

Although you can do it, but the preferred way is to write proper unit test using frameworks like Junit (@Test is from Junit framework).

Junit framework makes testing easier and is considered standard in Java Development. You can use features like Assert to check the output of method or fields inside it. Thus Ex 2 is preferred in industry. refer this test file written using junit framework -

https://github.com/akashchandwani/Algorithms/blob/master/Algorithms/test/sorting/SortingTest.java .

Here's a junit tutorial you can refer to, there are several available on web, you can choose what suits you.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Comment: Thanks :) I got it. It has little different but I think not important for Junior developer :) is it ok ?

Comment: Junit would be the right way to do it, since it provides lot of methods for testing and could make your code cleaner and maintainable. If Ex.1 works for you can go with it as well, it's also a test but not recommended though.

Comment: I understood that. Thanks for advice :)

Comment: you're Welcome :)